# How to select columns based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame and I wonder how to select columns that contain any of the substrings from a given list `targets`:

```
targets = ["c1", "c2"]

df = 
c1_targ   c2xxx  c3abc
...       ...    ...
```

Expected result:

```
df = 
    c1_targ   c2xxx
    ...       ...
```

This is what I tried:

```
cols = [[True if col in df.columns else False] for col in targets]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join each value of string by `|` for regex `OR` - `'c1|c2'` is `c1` or `c2` and then filter by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
targets = ["c1", "c2"]

df1 = df.filter(regex='|'.join(targets))
```

Or create mask by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for get all rows and columns by mask:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(targets))]
```

---

```
print (df1)
  c1_targ c2xxx
0     ...   ...
```

Comment: Could you please explain why do you use `regex='|'`?

Comment: `regex='|'.join(targets)` will create `'c1|c2'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
new_col = [x for x in df.columns if any(y in x for y in targets)]
df = df[df.columns.intersection(new_col)]
```

Comment: Why do you use `intersection`?

Comment: To select the columns that are both in the original `df` and in the new list created in the previous line. You can use also `df = df[df.columns & new_col]` for example